# Connect/Authenticate SPO with VBA (excel)

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, online, vba

I am trying to connect to Sharepoint Online with Excel VBA script to create or delete items in a list. The problem is how to authenticate properly to SPO.
I have checked the site with instruction:

- http://www.sharepoint-insight.com/2016/03/21/step-by-step-sharepoint-online-authentiaction-process-via-http-protocol/

When trying to follow the sequence of the instruction via a Chrome app (ARC) to test the webservices it works properly however when I build the same to complete it fails on the last step:

I am able to get a BinarySecurityToken
After that there should be authed via https://XXXXX.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/idcrl.svc to gain the SPOIDCRL cookie which can be used in every next webservice (fe REST call to create list items). however in vba I get an 401 Unauthorized error. But when I do the same in ARC it works properly. I even can use the returned Cookie in my VBA Excel to create/delete list items (after gaining context)

```
Dim objXMLHTTP As Object
Dim url As String

url = "https://XXXXXXX.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/idcrl.svc"

Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

With objXMLHTTP
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "BPOSIDCRL <LONG BASE64 STRING>"
    .setRequestHeader "X-IDCRL_ACCEPTED", "t"
    .send
End With
```

Comment: had same problem, simply adding a slash (`/`) to the end of the url corrected the issue for me --> `url = ".../_vti_bin/idcrl.svc/"` <-- try adding slash to end...

Comment: Can you please explain what this code is doing? My requirement is - I need to make a connect from MS Access to SharePoint Online site. Access utility has Tables which are hosted at SharePoint site. So how I can make a connect to the site thorugh VBA code? Also, in the above code is there any need to pass the credentials ?